# Help me with proof concerning functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

**Problem:** Let $X$ and $Y$ be non-empty sets and let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a function. We define $F: P(Y) \rightarrow P(X)$ by $F(B) = f^{-1}(B)$ for all $B \in P(Y)$.

Proof that $F$ is injective if and only if $f$ is surjective.

**Attempt at a proof:** Suppose $F$ is injective. Then from $F(A) = F(B)$ it follows that $A = B$. Now let $y \in Y$ be an arbitrary element. Then we have to show that there is an $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$. Choose $B = Y$. Then $F(Y) = f^{-1}(Y)$. Hence we have that $x \in f^{-1}(Y)$ and so $x \in F(Y)$.

I'm not sure how to continue. Is it allowed to choose $B = Y$ or should I take another path?

Comment: the problem is that $x\in F(Y)$ does not imply that $f(x)=y$, only that $f(x)\in Y$.

Comment: Yes, so how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I\in\wp(Y)$ be the image of $f$, i.e. $I:=\{f(x)\mid x\in X\}$.

Then $F(I)=X=F(Y)$ and injectivity of $F$ tells us that $I=Y$ or equivalently: $f$ is surjective.

Conversely let $f$ be surjective and $F\left(A\right)=F\left(B\right)$.

Now let $y\in A$. Then $f\left(x\right)=y\in A$ for some $x$ (since $f$ is surjective) so
that $x\in F\left(A\right)=F\left(B\right)$.

Then $y=f\left(x\right)\in B$
and proved is now $A\subseteq B$.

By symmetry we also have $B\subseteq A$
so that $A=B$, proving injectivity of $F$.

Comment: Looks good. In the first part, did you conclude that $F(I) = X$ on the basis of $F(B) = f^{-1}(B)$? How do you know that it equals all of $X$?

Comment: $F(I)=f^{-1}(I)=\{x\in X\mid f(x)\in I\}$ and by the definition of $I$ it is clear that $f(x)\in I$ is true for **every** $x\in X$. So we come to $F(I)=X$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the idea. Suppose $f$ is not subjective. Then there is a $y\in Y\setminus f(X)$ Let $Y'=Y\setminus\{y\}$, then $F(Y)=F(Y')=X$.

Comment: How did you conclude that $F(Y) = F(Y') = X$ ? It's only allowed to say that $Y = Y'$.

Comment: Let $B=f(X)$ and $B'=\{y\}\cup B$. Now $F(B)=X$, but $F(B')=X$ also since $y$ is not in $F(X)$. In other words, adding $y$ to $B$ does not add anything to $F(B)$.

Answer (score 0):

f is surjective => V y ∈ Y, there exists at least one x ∈ X | f(x)=y

There could be a case of multiple x1,x2 ∈ X | f(x1)=f(x2)

F is chosen P(Y) → P(X)  by F(B)=f'(B)  for all B ∈ P(Y) (where f' refers to inverse of f)

i.e V y ∈ y, there exists x and only one x | f'(y)=x

So V x ∈ X, there exists y ∈ Y | f(x)=y & f'(y)=x

Thus F is injective.

Comment: What about the other implication: F is injective -> f is surjective?

Comment: To repeat the line
F is chosen P(Y) → P(X) by F(B)=f'(B) for all B ∈ P(Y) (where f' refers to inverse of f)
This => there is no y ∈ P(Y), which do not have a f'(y).